# Why can you return a private struct from a closure

Tags: rust

Rust normally has strict privacy laws, you can't return a private type from a public function.

However, it seems like you are able to return a type created in a closure from that closure. But why? Why are you allowed to return a private struct from a closure?

```rust
fn main () {
    let closure = || {
        struct Sample;

        Sample
    };
}
```

Comment: Closures do not have their own scope.  The struct is hoisted to the scope of the module.

Comment: own namespace** I suppose is a better way to word it.

Comment: that just an edge case, this will not be useful anyway

Comment: @Stargateur it can actually be useful, `Sample` can have fields and methods that can be accessed from outside the closure

Comment: @Mendy just like you know... declare Sample not in the closure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can still do things with it. The structure isn't sealed inside the closure, it just so happens that we can't use the name `Sample` directly outside of the closure. But we can still access its methods. Consider

```
fn main () {
  let closure = || {
    struct Sample;

    impl Sample {
      fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello, world! :)");
      }
    }

    Sample
  };
  let s = closure();
  s.say_hello();
}
```

The `main` function still knows that `s` has type `Sample`, and we can still call inherent methods like `say_hello` on it. The fact that you, as the programmer, can't say the name of the structure, is irrelevant.

---

Just to make it perfectly clear, based on feedback in the comments. Local structures and `fn` functions in Rust (i.e. structures and functions written *inside* other functions) are not actually local. They're internally hoisted to the enclosing module from a visibility standpoint. A function can't *own* a structure, only a module can. You can't reference the name `Sample` in the module scope, but that's where it's being hoisted to internally. If it helps, you can think of it as though `Sample` is being lifted to a top-level `struct __mangledname_internal_Sample` at the top of your file. It's still there, just not with a name that you can access.

Comment: Why than is it different from returning a private type from a pub fn?

Comment: Because `closure` isn't a `pub fn`. It's a local variable inside your module. It would not be possible to return `closure` from a public function, since `closure`'s type contains a local (private) structure. But currently, there's nothing public about it.

Comment: @Mendy The closure doesn't own the struct definition, the namespace of the _module_ does which is the name of the containing file in lieu of an explicit `mod` block.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's roughly being generated per your rust code:

```rust
struct Closure {
    s : Sample
}

impl FnOnce<()> for Closure {
    type Output = Sample;
    fn call_once(self) -> Self::Output {
        self.s
    }
}
```

The information regarding defining the struct and the `impl` blocks are hoisted to the module level when inside of a closure. So this block below will be accessible at the module level:

```rust
 struct Sample;

 impl Sample {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello, world! :)");
    }
 }
```

Therefore, nothing actually breaks the privacy rules as the Closure struct simply uses the Sample type defined at the module level

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, you haven't yet actually done anything with the closure. Try this one:

```rust
fn main () {
    let closure = some_stuff::public_function();
}

mod some_stuff {
    pub fn public_function () -> impl FnOnce() -> PrivateStruct {
        let closure = || {
            struct PrivateStruct;
            
            PrivateStruct
        };
        return closure
    }
}
```

And you'll get

```
 Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0412]: cannot find type `PrivateStruct` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:6:51
  |
6 |     pub fn public_function () -> impl FnOnce() -> PrivateStruct {
  |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: This still doesn't explain the _why_ and the answer is that `main` and the struct are in the same scope.